Evaluation of $\int_0^{\infty} \frac{e^{-x}\sin(ax)\ln(x)}{x}dx $ where $a > 0$ is a real constant.
Evaluation of
$$\int_0^{\infty} \frac{e^{-x}\sin(ax)\ln(x)}{x}dx $$ where $a > 0$ is a real constant.
I have attempted integration by parts, but when $u = \ln(x)$ and $dv = \frac {e^{-x} \sin(ax)} {x} dx$, then $du = \frac{dx}{x}$ and $v = \frac {e^{-x} \sin(ax)} {x} dx$ which I just couldn't find a closed-form expression for.
I have attempted solving using Laplace transforms and convolution to make it more manageable,
$$\mathcal{L}\{f(t)\}(s)=\int_0^{\infty}e^{-st}f(t)dt$$
The Laplace transform of $\ln(t)$ is
$$\mathcal{L}\{\ln(t)\}(s)= -\frac{\ln(s) + \gamma}{s}, \Bbb R(s)>0$$ so as the integrand is $\frac{\ln(x)}{x}$ it can be rewritten as
$$\frac {\ln(x)}{x}=\int_0^{\infty}e^{-xt}\ln(t)dt$$
$$\frac {\ln(x)}{x}=\int_0^{\infty}(e^{-t}-e^{-xt})\frac{dt}{t}$$now substituting
$$\int_0^{\infty}\frac{e^{-x}\sin(ax)}{x}\left(\int_0^{\infty}(e^{-t}-e^{-xt})\frac{dt}{t}\right)dx $$
we assume Fubini's theorem allows us to interchange the order of integration (verifying absolute convergence)$$\int_0^{\infty}\frac{dt}{t}\left(e^{-t}\int_0^{\infty}\frac{e^{-x}\sin(ax)}{x}dx-\int_0^{\infty}\frac{e^{-x(1+t)}\sin(ax)}{x}dx\right)$$
the inner integrals are of the form $K(\lambda)=\int_0^{\infty}\frac{e^{-\lambda x}\sin(ax)}{x}dx$ which is known and can be expressed as $K(\lambda)=\arctan\left(\frac{a}{\lambda}\right), \lambda>0$. We can use $K(\lambda)$ for the inner integrals.
For $\lambda=1$, $K(1)=\arctan(a)$. For $\lambda=1+t$, $K(1+t)=\arctan\left(\frac{a}{1+t}\right)$.
Substituting back into the integral,$$\int_0^{\infty}\frac{dt}{t}\left[e^{-t}\arctan(a)-\arctan\left(\frac{a}{1+t}\right)\right]dt$$
$$=\arctan(a)\int_0^{\infty}\frac{e^{-t}-1}{t}dt+\int_0^{\infty}\frac{1}{t}\left[\arctan(a)-\arctan\left(\frac{a}{1+t}\right)\right]dt$$
our first integral is $\int_0^{\infty}\frac{e^{-t}-1}{t}dt$, which leads to a logarithmic divergence as $t$ approaches $0$. No other simplifications really work and maybe you could introduce a regularisation or something but I'm just stuck. Evaluations of the second integral also went to $\int_0^{\infty}\frac{1}{t}\arctan\left(\frac{at}{1+a^2+a^2t}\right)dt$, also extremely difficult to evaluate.
Thanks in advance!

I would try two things: 1. Use Frullani's formula to represent the $\ln$. You'll get some exponentials that will nicely square off with the exponential in your denominator. Then represent your function as a parametric function over the parameter $a$, i.e. $I(a)$ and apply Feynman's trick.

edit: numerator.

Assume the simpler twin integrals
\begin{align}
&\int_0^{\infty} {\frac{e^{-x}\sin ax}x}dx =\tan^{-1}a\\
& \int_0^{\infty} {\frac{e^{-x} (1-\cos ax)}x}dx =\frac12\ln(1+a^2)
\end{align}
as well as $  \int_0^{\infty} e^{-x}\ln x\ dx =-\gamma$ are known. Then
\begin{align}
 I(a)=&\int_0^{\infty} \frac{e^{-x}\sin ax\ln x}{x}dx \\
I’(a)=& \int_0^{\infty} {e^{-x}\cos ax\ln x}\ dx 
= \frac1a\int_0^{\infty} {e^{-x}\ln x}\ d(\sin ax)\\
\overset{ibp}=&\  \frac1{a^2}\int_0^{\infty} {e^{-x}\ln x}\ d(1-\cos ax)-\frac1a \int_0^{\infty} {\frac{e^{-x}\sin ax}x}\ dx \\
\overset{ibp} =&-\frac1{a^2}I’(a)-\frac{\gamma}{a^2} -
+\frac1{2a^2}\ln(1+a^2)-\frac1a \tan^{-1}a \\
 =& -\frac{\gamma}{1+a^2}-\frac12\bigg[\ln(1+a^2)\tan^{-1}a\bigg]’\\
\end{align}
Thus
\begin{align}
&\int_0^{\infty} \frac{e^{-x}\sin ax\ln x}{x}dx \\
=&\int_0^a I’(t)dt
=-\gamma  \tan^{-1}a -\frac12 \ln(1+a^2)\tan^{-1}a
\end{align}
For comparison, its twin is
\begin{align}
&\int_0^{\infty} \frac{e^{-x}(1-\cos ax)\ln x}{x}dx \\
=&-\frac{ \gamma }2\ln(1+a^2) -\frac18 \ln^2(1+a^2)+\frac12 (\tan^{-1}a)^2
\end{align}

+1. If anyone's unfamiliar with the assumed results, their $a$-derivatives are the real & imaginary parts of $\int_0^\infty e^{-(1-ia)x}\mathrm{d}x=\frac{1}{1-ia}$.

If you consider
$$\int \frac{e^{-(1-i a)x }\log(x)}{x }\,dx $$  you face  a generalized hypergeometric function (have a look here) plus a few more or less pleasant terms.
Using the bounds for the imaginary part
$$\int_0^{\infty} \frac{e^{-x}\sin(ax)\log(x)}{x}\,dx=-\left(\log
   \left(\sqrt{a^2+1}\right)+\gamma\right) \tan ^{-1}(a)$$
If you work with (as you wrote it),
$$\int_0^{\infty}\frac{dt}{t}\left[e^{-t}\arctan(a)-\arctan\left(\frac{a}{1+t}\right)\right]\,dt$$ the singularity is removable since  if
$$A=\frac{1}{t}\left[e^{-t}\arctan(a)-\arctan\left(\frac{a}{1+t}\right)\right]$$ $$A=\left(\frac{a}{a^2+1}-\tan
   ^{-1}(a)\right)+ \left(\frac{1}{2}
   \tan^{-1}(a)-\frac{a}{\left(a^2+1\right)  ^2}\right)\,t
+O\left(t^2\right)$$
We also have
$$A=\frac{e^{-t} \tan ^{-1}(a)}{t}-\frac a {t^2}+\frac a {t^3}+O\left(\frac{1}{t^4}\right)$$
Using the logarithmic representation of the arctangent function, the antiderivative is given in terms of the exponential integral function, a few logarithms and polylogarithms of complex arguments.
Using the bounds, the same result.

The desired integral
$$I(a)=\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-x}\sin(ax)\ln x}xdx=\Im\frac{\partial}{\partial s}\,\bigg|_{s=-1}\int_0^\infty e^{-x(1-ia)}x^sdx$$
Making the substitution $x=t(1+ia)$ (what is, in fact, integration along a segment of a circle in the complex plane, where the integrals along a small arch around $z=0$ and along a big arch tend to zero as the radiuses of the arches tend to zero and $\infty$ correspondingly).
$$J(a,s)=\int_0^\infty e^{-x(1-ia)}x^sdx=(1+ia)^{1+s}\int_0^\infty t^se^{-t(1+a^2)}dt$$
$$=\frac{(1+ia)^{1+s}}{(1+a^2)^{1+s}}\Gamma(1+s)$$
Denoting $s=-1+\epsilon$ and taking the imaginary part
$$I(a)=\frac{\partial}{\partial\epsilon}\,\bigg|_{\epsilon=0}\frac{\Gamma(\epsilon)}{(1+a^2)^{\frac\epsilon2}}\sin(\epsilon\arctan a)=\frac{\partial}{\partial\epsilon}\,\bigg|_{\epsilon=0}\frac{\Gamma(1+\epsilon)}{(1+a^2)^{\frac\epsilon2}}\frac{\sin(\epsilon\arctan a)}\epsilon$$
$$=-\left(\gamma+\frac{\ln(1+a^2)}2\right)\arctan a$$

$$I(a)=\int_0^{\infty} \frac{e^{-x}\sin ax\ln x}{x}dx$$
Using the Taylor series for $\sin(ax)$,
$$I(a)=\int_0^{\infty} \frac{e^{-x}\ln(x)}{x}\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k(ax)^{2k+1}}{(2k+1)!}\,dx=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k(a)^{2k+1}}{(2k+1)!}\int_0^{\infty} e^{-x}x^{2k}\ln(x)\,dx$$
Consider the first derivative of the gamma function;
$$\Gamma^{'}_n=\int_0^{\infty}e^{-x}x^{n-1}\ln(x)\,dx$$
$$\underset{n\to 2n+1}\implies\Gamma^{'}_{2n+1}=\int_0^{\infty}e^{-x}x^{2n}\ln(x)\,dx=\Gamma_{2n+1}\psi(2n+1)\implies (2n)!\psi(2n+1)$$
$$I(a)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k(a)^{2k+1}}{(2k+1)!}(2k)!\psi(2k+1)\implies \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k(a)^{2k+1}}{(2k+1)}\psi(2k+1)$$
So our integral is essentially a weird sum of a weird (combination of multiple taylor series in disguise);
$$I(a)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k(a)^{2k+1}}{(2k+1)}\psi(2k+1)=a(-\gamma)-\frac{a^3}{3}\left(\frac32-\gamma\right)+\frac{a^5}{5}\left(\frac{25}{12}-\gamma\right)-\cdots$$
Regrouping it to make it look nicer, we get;
$$I(a)=-\gamma\left[a-\frac{a^3}{3}+\frac{a^5}{5}-\cdots\right]-\frac{a^3}{2}+\frac{5a^5}{12}-\cdots$$
Using this, and the Taylor series of arctan function, we can conclude,
$$\boxed{\color{blue}{\int_0^{\infty} \frac{e^{-x}\sin ax\ln x}{x}dx=-\gamma \tan^{-1}(a)-\frac{1}{2}\ln(1+a^2)\tan^{-1}(a)}}$$
Note:

$\psi(1)=-\gamma$
$\psi(3)=\frac{3}{2}-\gamma$
$\psi(5)=\frac{25}{12}-\gamma$
$\psi(7)=\frac{49}{20}-\gamma$ and so on


I have utilized this, this, this and this


Alternative solution.
Remark. Three years ago, I have evaluated the integral for $a=1$. The approach works for general $a > 0$.
I found that the OP used the similar approach.
Using the identities
\begin{align*}
 \frac{1}{x} &= \int_0^\infty \mathrm{e}^{-x t}\, \mathrm{d} t, \\
 \ln x &= \int_0^\infty \frac{\mathrm{e}^{-s} - \mathrm{e}^{-xs}}{s}\,\mathrm{d} s,
\end{align*}
we have
\begin{align*}
 I &= \int_0^\infty \mathrm{e}^{-x}\sin ax
 \left(\int_0^\infty \mathrm{e}^{-x t}\, \mathrm{d} t\right)
 \left(\int_0^\infty \frac{\mathrm{e}^{-s} - \mathrm{e}^{-xs} }{s}\,\mathrm{d} s\right)\mathrm{d}x\\[8pt]
 &= \int_0^\infty \frac{1}{s}
 \left[\int_0^\infty \left(\int_0^\infty \mathrm{e}^{-x(1 + t) - s}\sin ax\, \mathrm{d} x - \int_0^\infty \mathrm{e}^{-x(1 + s + t)}\sin ax \, \mathrm{d} x \right)\mathrm{d} t\right]\mathrm{d} s\\[8pt]
 &= \int_0^\infty \frac{1}{s}
 \left[\int_0^\infty \left( \mathrm{e}^{-s}\, \frac{a}{(1 + t)^2 + a^2} - \frac{a}{(1 + s + t)^2 + a^2} \right)\mathrm{d} t\right]\mathrm{d} s  \tag{1}\\[8pt]
 &= \int_0^\infty \frac{1}{s}
 \left[- \frac{\pi}{2} + \arctan\frac{1 + s}{a} +  \mathrm{e}^{-s}\left(\frac{\pi}{2} - \arctan\frac{1}{a}\right)\right]\mathrm{d} s\\[8pt]
 &= \lim_{c\to 0^{+}}
 \int_c^\infty \frac{1}{s}
 \left[- \frac{\pi}{2} + \arctan\frac{1 + s}{a} +  \mathrm{e}^{-s}\left(\frac{\pi}{2} - \arctan\frac{1}{a}\right)\right]\mathrm{d} s\\[8pt]
 &= \lim_{c\to 0^{+}}
 \left[ \left(\frac{\pi}{2} - \arctan\frac{1 + c}{a} -  \mathrm{e}^{-c}\left(\frac{\pi}{2} - \arctan\frac{1}{a}\right)\right)\ln c \right. \\[6pt]
 &\qquad\qquad\left.  + \left(\frac{\pi}{2} - \arctan\frac{1}{a}\right)\int_c^\infty \mathrm{e}^{-s}\ln s \, \mathrm{d} s - \int_c^\infty \frac{a\ln s}{(s+1)^2 + a^2}\,\mathrm{d} s\right]    \tag{2}\\[12pt]
 &= - \left(\frac{\pi}{2} - \arctan\frac{1}{a}\right)\gamma - \frac{\ln(a^2 + 1)}{2} \left(\frac{\pi}{2} - \arctan\frac{1}{a}\right). \tag{3}
\end{align*}
Explanations:
(1): $\int \mathrm{e}^{-bx}\sin ax \, \mathrm{d} x = -\frac{b\sin ax + a \cos ax}{b^2 + a^2}\mathrm{e}^{-bx}  + C$;
(2): the IBP (Integration By Parts);
(3): $\lim_{c\to 0^{+}} \left(\frac{\pi}{2} - \arctan\frac{1 + c}{a} -  \mathrm{e}^{-c}\left(\frac{\pi}{2} - \arctan\frac{1}{a}\right)\right)\ln c = 0$,
and $\int_0^\infty \mathrm{e}^{-s}\ln s \, \mathrm{d} s = - \gamma$
where $\gamma$ is the Euler-Mascheroni constant,
and $\int_0^\infty \frac{\ln s}{(s+1)^2 + a^2}\,\mathrm{d} s = \frac{\ln(a^2 + 1)}{2a}\left(\frac{\pi}{2} - \arctan\frac{1}{a}\right)$ (the proof is given at the end).

A very nice proof of $\int_0^\infty \frac{\ln s}{(s+1)^2 + a^2}\,\mathrm{d} s = \frac{\ln(a^2 + 1)}{2a}\left(\frac{\pi}{2} - \arctan\frac{1}{a}\right)$ by @Kelenner:
Let $J = \int_0^\infty \frac{\ln s}{(s+1)^2 + a^2}\,\mathrm{d} s$.
With the substitution $s = \frac{1+a^2}{u}$, we have
$$J = \int_0^\infty \frac{\ln (1+a^2) - \ln u}{(u+1)^2 + a^2}\,\mathrm{d} u
= \int_0^\infty \frac{\ln (1+a^2) }{(u+1)^2+a^2}\,\mathrm{d} u - J$$
which results in
$J = \frac{1}{2} \int_0^\infty \frac{\ln (1+a^2) }{(u+1)^2 + a^2}\,\mathrm{d} u = \frac{\ln (1+a^2)}{2}\arctan\frac{1+u}{a}\vert_0^\infty = \frac{\ln(a^2 + 1)}{2a}\left(\frac{\pi}{2} - \arctan\frac{1}{a}\right)$. We are done.
